# Export Azure Release Pipeline Automated Results to Teams

Tags: azure-devops, automation, automated-tests, microsoft-teams

I am trying to find a way to export Azure Release Pipeline Automated Results to Teams

I currently use the Azure Pipelines plug in on teams however as I have the tests run on many devices and have two pipelines for web and mobile which means i'm getting about 20+ notifications a day which isn't very readable.

I wonder if anyone else had a similar issue and found a way round it?
Possibly just getting 1 message per pipeline which included each stage and if it passed/failed?

Thanks!

Comment: So you're basically asking for a way to send a custom message from your pipeline to teams, is that correct?

Comment: Correct! @GetShifting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're looking to send a custom message to Teams I would advice you to use the webhook functionality in Teams. Microsoft has some good documentation on [creating webhooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/add-incoming-webhook?tabs=dotnet) and [formatting the message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/connectors-using?tabs=PowerShell) for it. In good SO tradition, here are the steps:

- In Teams, go to the Channel and go to Connectors using the dropdown menu
- Click Add
- Configure an incoming webhook and save the url that you'll get from it

Now you need to format and send a message to the webhook. I'll show you using powershell which is an easy way to add a custom task in your pipeline:

```
# First set some useful variables and define your messagecard
$header = "Test results"
$prefix = "[In Progress]"
$themeColor = "#0000FF"
$img = "https://cdn.you.want.to.use.com/it/image.png"

$teamsMessage = @{
    "@type"           = "MessageCard"
    "@context"        = "http://schema.org/extensions"
    "themeColor"      = $themeColor
    "summary"         = "$prefix $header"
    sections        = @(
        @{
            activityTitle    = "$prefix $header"
            activitySubtitle = "your subtitle"
            activityImage    = $img
        },
        @{
            facts = @(
                @{
                    name  = 'Pipeline'
                    value = "[$definition]($definitionUrl)"
                },
                @{
                    name  = 'Run'
                    value = "[$buildId]($BuildUrl)"
                }
            )
        }
    )
}

# Second, send the message to teams
# Convert message to json
$jsonObject = (ConvertTo-Json $teamsMessage -Depth 100)

# Log het jsonObject
$jsonObject | Out-Host

# Send teams message
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -ContentType 'Application/Json' -Body $jsonObject -Uri $webhookUrl

if ($response -ne 1) {
    Write-Warning "Response: $response"
    Write-Host "##vso[task.complete result=SucceededWithIssues;]"
}
```